# t:savestate in jsf - impact on page load time

Tags: jsf

Recently i came across a jsp page where in i saw

1. The usage of `<t:savestate>` tag twice for same bean .
2. Also usage of many `<t:savestate>` tags for bean and many variables which were not required for that page functionality but still present on the page, simply obsolete.

My question is does `<t:savestate>` has any impact on performance/page load time point of view for above two scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `t:savestate` does is to save data in the view scope, by storing the value resulting of the value expression in the component itself. So, while it certainly does have some impact on performance, it depends mostly on the size (and amount) of the objects.

If I've understood its implementation correctly ([source code here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/myfaces/tomahawk/trunk/core20/src/main/java/org/apache/myfaces/custom/savestate/UISaveState.java?revision=1395213&view=markup)), it's going to hold a copy of each value you pass, unless the value you passed is an instance of [StateHolder](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/StateHolder.html) (like several JSF components such as inputs, datatables, etc).

So, you probably would do good in removing the unnecessary tags, for cleaning things up.
But if your major concern is performance, I don't know if it will make much difference, and you should profile before start making changes for performance reasons.

Also, make sure to note if the duplicated `t:saveState` tags are inside the same `h:form`. If they are in different `h:form`s, they are probably needed in both places.

Comment: Thanks for the quick turn around. I too agree that any useless tag in code is always useless , and needs a clean up. Will try to profile after removing unnecessry tags from jsp.